# How to declare and initialize a list from template .h and .hpp

Tags: c++

I have to make an Queue from a STL List in C++.
How do I create and initialize a List as a class member in a template ?

This is the .h :

```
#pragma once

template <class T>
class QueueQ
{
public:
    QueueQ(void);
    ~QueueQ(void);
    bool empty(void);
    int size(void);
    T front(void);
    void push(T _object);
    void pop(void);

private:
    int a;
    list<T> m_list;
};
```

This is the .hpp :

```
#include "QueueQ.h"
#include <list>
using namespace std;

template <class T>
QueueQ<T>::QueueQ(void)
{
    this->m_list<T>;
}
```

How could I make m_list as a class member I can access from this->m_list ?

Thanks !

Comment: As you've declared it as a member variable, it's automatically created and initialised.

Comment: pragma once is missing the `#`. You need to include `<list>` in the header otherwise you can't use it there. It's in the `std` namespace, so your declaration should look like `std::list<T> m_list;`. And it's automatically initialized for you by default, so you don't need to do anything special in your constructor.

Comment: Thanks Cameron, problem solve, only needed the std::. I'm not used to code in C++.

Answer (score 0):

If you do need to explicitly call the constructor (either to pass arguments, or to avoid default initialization of primitive types), use a constructor-initializer

```
template <class T>
QueueQ<T>::QueueQ(void) : m_list(list, of, constructor, arguments), m_answer(42)
{}
```

Note that the members are initialized in the order they are declared in the *class*, not the order they appear in the ctor-initializer.

Also, the braced body of a constructor should almost always be empty (among other reasons, you'll get nasty problems with exceptions).